# Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'FirestoreSource' that does not accept a closure

Tags: swiftui

I get error when I use .getDocuments { snapshot, error in }

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import FirebaseStorage

class MedicineViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    let db: Firestore
    @Published var medicines = [Medicine]()
    
    private init() {
        self.db = Firestore.firestore()
    }

    func getData(_ userId: String) {
        
        let collectionMedicine = self.db.collection("users").document(userId).collection("medicines")
        
        collectionMedicine.getDocuments { snapshot, error in // This line causes error

            if error == nil {

                if let snapshot = snapshot {

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        for d in snapshot.documents {

                            self.medicines.append(Medicine(id: d.id,
                                        name: d["name"],
                                            prescription: d["prescription"],
                                        number: d["number"],
                                        taken: d["taken"]))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                // Handle the error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However funny thing about my situation is that code that is exact same with this does not cause error

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import FirebaseStorage


class UserViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var list = [User]()
    let db: Firestore
    
    private init() {
        self.db = Firestore.firestore()
    }
    
    func getData() {
        
        self.db.collection("users").getDocuments { snapshot, error in
            
            if error == nil {
                
                if let snapshot = snapshot {
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        
                        for d in snapshot.documents {

                            self.list.append(User(
                                id: d.documentID,
                                email: d["email"] as? String ?? "",
                                pw: d["pw"] as? String ?? ""))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                // Handle the error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can't understand why UserViewModel does not cause error while MedicineViewModel do. I found some people who have simliar problem with me but their solution couldn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you figured this out, but for those that are coming after me:

I was having this issue, and I was tearing my hair out trying to figure out what was wrong, and this post was the *only* question that matched what I was experiencing.

The problem is in the version that isn't working and is showing you that error you aren't converting the values you get from keying into your document object into `String`s (or whatever they should be) from `Any`

So if you update

```
self.medicines.append(Medicine(id: d.id,
                               name: d["name"],
                               prescription: d["prescription"],
                               number: d["number"],
                               taken: d["taken"]))
```

to

```
self.medicines.append(Medicine(id: d.id,
                               name: d["name"] as? String ?? "",
                               prescription: d["prescription"] as? String ?? "",
                               number: d["number"] as? String ?? "",
                               taken: d["taken"] as? String ?? ""))
```

it should work. Of course assuming that every parameter in your `Medicine` initializer is a `String`.

Hope this saves someone a few hours of trying to figure this out since the error message led me on a wild goose chase thinking I couldn't append to an array inside of this callback. It's always the little things.